# Using DJI video feed with Vision Framework

Tags: ios, swift, dji-sdk, ios-vision

I'm working on an app that uses the video feed from the DJI Mavic 2 and runs it through a machine learning model to identify objects.

I managed to get my app to preview the feed from the drone using this [sample DJI project](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/iOS-FPVDemo-Swift), but I'm having a lot of trouble trying to get the video data into a format that's usable by the [`Vision` framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision).

I used [this example from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/recognizing_objects_in_live_capture) as a guide to create my model (which is working!) but it looks I need to create a `VNImageRequestHandler` object which is created with a `cvPixelBuffer` of type `CMSampleBuffer` in order to use `Vision`.

Any idea how to make this conversion? Is there a better way to do this?

```
class DJICameraViewController: UIViewController, DJIVideoFeedListener, DJISDKManagerDelegate, DJICameraDelegate, VideoFrameProcessor {

// ...

func videoFeed(_ videoFeed: DJIVideoFeed, didUpdateVideoData rawData: Data) {
    let videoData = rawData as NSData
    let videoBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: videoData.length)
    videoData.getBytes(videoBuffer, length: videoData.length)
    DJIVideoPreviewer.instance().push(videoBuffer, length: Int32(videoData.length))        
}

// MARK: VideoFrameProcessor Protocol Implementation
func videoProcessorEnabled() -> Bool {
    // This is never called
    return true
}

func videoProcessFrame(_ frame: UnsafeMutablePointer<VideoFrameYUV>!) {
    // This is never called
    let pixelBuffer = frame.pointee.cv_pixelbuffer_fastupload as! CVPixelBuffer
    
    let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, orientation: exifOrientationFromDeviceOrientation(), options: [:])
    
    do {
        try imageRequestHandler.perform(self.requests)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
} // End of DJICameraViewController class
```

**EDIT**: from what I've gathered from DJI's (spotty) documentation, it looks like the video feed is compressed H264. They claim the `DJIWidget` includes helper methods for decompression, but I haven't had success in understanding how to use them correctly because there is no documentation surrounding its use.

**EDIT 2**: Here's the [issue I created on GitHub](https://github.com/dji-sdk/DJIWidget/issues/8) for the DJIWidget framework

**EDIT 3**: Updated code snippet with additional methods for `VideoFrameProcessor`, removing old code from `videoFeed` method

**EDIT 4**: Details about how to extract the pixel buffer successfully and utilize it can be found in [this comment from GitHub](https://github.com/dji-sdk/DJIWidget/issues/9#issuecomment-444483578)

**EDIT 5**: It's been years since I worked on this but since there is still some activity here, [here's a relevant gist](https://gist.github.com/SpencerKaiser/3908ab1c661dfe87fa87bf4f22f638dc) I created to help others. I can't remember specifics around how/why this was relevant, but hopefully it makes sense!

Comment: please put all follow up and comments here. Don't create issue on GitHub. We have deprecated the support for GitHub issue

Answer (score 3):

The steps ：

1. Call `DJIVideoPreviewer`’s `push:length:` method and input the `rawData`. Inside `DJIVideoPreviewer`, if you have used `VideoPreviewerSDKAdapter` please skip this. (H.264 parsing and decoding steps will be performed once you do this.)
2. Conform to the `VideoFrameProcessor` protocol and call `DJIVideoPreviewer.registFrameProcessor` to register the `VideoFrameProcessor` protocol object.
3. `VideoFrameProcessor` protocol’s `videoProcessFrame:` method will output the `VideoFrameYUV` data.
4. Get the `CVPixelBuffer` data. `VideoFrameYUV` struct has a `cv_pixelbuffer_fastupload` field, this data is actually of type `CVPixelBuffer` when hardware decoding is turned on. If you are using software decoding, you will need to create a `CVPixelBuffer` yourself and copy the data from the `VideoFrameYUV`'s `luma`, `chromaB` and `chromaR` field.

---

Code:

```
VideoFrameYUV* yuvFrame; // the VideoFrameProcessor output
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = NULL;
CVReturn resulst = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                       yuvFrame-> width,
                                       yuvFrame -> height, 
                                  kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8Planar,
                                       NULL,
                                       &pixelBuffer);
if (kCVReturnSuccess != CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0) || pixelBuffer == NULL) {
    return;
}
long yPlaneWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0);
long yPlaneHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer,0);
long uPlaneWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1);
long uPlaneHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1);
long vPlaneWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 2);
long vPlaneHeight =  CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 2);
uint8_t* yDestination = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0);
memcpy(yDestination, yuvFrame->luma, yPlaneWidth * yPlaneHeight);
uint8_t* uDestination = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 1);
memcpy(uDestination, yuvFrame->chromaB, uPlaneWidth * uPlaneHeight);
uint8_t* vDestination = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 2);
memcpy(vDestination, yuvFrame->chromaR, vPlaneWidth * vPlaneHeight);
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
```

Comment: It looks like my VideoFrameProcessor methods are never being called... any idea why that might be? And about the software decoding, how would I know which (hardware/software) is enabled??

Comment: You have implemented the `VideoFrameProcessor` protocol methods, but it looks like you might be missing the `registFrameProcessor` call which registers the `VideoFrameProcessor` protocol.

Comment: We're getting closer; those methods are now being called but now I can't access `cv_pixelbuffer_fastupload`. I'm trying to get to it via `frame.pointee.cv_pixelbuffer_fastupload as! CVPixelBuffer` but I get an error: `'Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<VideoFrameYUV>>' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'pointee' of wrapped base type`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ah the issue is that `cv_pixelbuffer_fastupload` is `nil` so it looks like I have to create a `CVPixelBuffer` from the values specified above. What method should I use for the creation?

Comment: The `cv_pixelbuffer_fastupload` is nil because hardware decoding is not enabled. `DJIVideoPreviwer` has an property named `enableHardwareDecode` that needs to be set to YES.

Comment: If want to manually create a `CVPixelBuffer`,First of all,we need to know the type of YUV frame. `DJIVideoPreviewer` software decodes it outputted YUV420 8 bit. code is on answer.

Comment: BTW `enableHardwareDecode` not support in iOS simulator.

Comment: @dji-dev-Tim I tried `enableHardwareDecode` but it didn't work. I was able to get the other method to work though.

Comment: @dji-dev-Tim would you be able to provide me with an email address? I have a couple other questions that should be quick, but adding them to this question doesn't seem like a good idea...

Comment: @Spencer can you share more details on your issue with `enableHardwareDecode `? Thanks!

Comment: @Spencer could you share how you made the delegate method `videoProcessFrame ` work? For me, the method is not called even though I've registered the frame processor: `DJIVideoPreviewer.instance().registFrameProcessor(self)`. Any ideas?

Comment: I was never able to get enableHardwareDecode to function, I'm fairly certain it's a bug. Although the DJI team doesn't like to use GitHub, I'm going to open an issue there. Not sure why they choose to go against industry standards on open source...

Comment: @Spencer Have you been able to pull out a CGImage or so from the videoProcessFrame method?

Comment: @Spencer we update our sample code. Please check it and try it with an iOS device. Don't use the simulator. Any question please comment here.

Comment: @dji-dev-Tim I'm having a similar issue with cv_pixelbuffer_fastupload being nil in func videoProcessFrame(_ frame: UnsafeMutablePointer<VideoFrameYUV>!) on a device when I'm trying to grab the individual frames. However, DJIVideoPreviewer.instance()?.enableHardwareDecode is returning true. I'm not using any of the VideoPreviewerSDKAdapter classes. Perhaps I need to be? I've tested with the FPV in the DJISdkDemo app on a device, and that cv_pixelbuffer_fastupload is not nil. Not sure if that adapter class usage is required or not. Not sure if this is the same bug Spencer is running into.

Comment: I don't think so.  The `DJIVideoPreviewer` works well or not, Can you see the video stream.  Do you push the video data from `DJIVideoFeeder` into `DJIVideoPreviewer`?

Comment: I can see it. I do push the video data from `DJIVideoFeeder` into `DJIVideoPreviewer`

Comment: Please use https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-iOS Objc Sample code and try it.

Comment: @spencer Did you get this to work and were able to extract a pixel buffer that could be used in the app? Interested in how you got on. Can you share an source code?

Comment: @d0n13 I recently added some extra details to a related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dji-sdk/DJIWidget/issues/9#issuecomment-444483578). In that comment there's a link to a snippet for how to extract the pixel buffer. Good luck and sorry for the belated response!

Comment: I can't create `CIImage` from `VideoFrameYUV`. There is more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63227358/dji-videoframeyuv-to-ciimage-conversion